# The possible value of S

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is:
Find the all possible value of $S(a,b,c,d)= \frac{a}{a+b+d}+\frac{b}{a+b+c}+\frac{c}{b+c+d}+\frac{d}{a+c+d}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are positive.

I tried with $a+b+c+d=1$, but it seems I have a long way to go...

Comment: This is [IMO 1974 Problem 5](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/1974_IMO_Problems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim:** $1 < S < 2$

**Proof:** $S > \dfrac{a}{a+b+d+c} + \dfrac{b}{a+b+c+d} + \dfrac{c}{b+c+d+a} + \dfrac{d}{a+c+d+b} = 1$, and

$S < \dfrac{a+c}{a+b+c+d} + \dfrac{b+d}{a+b+c+d} + \dfrac{c+a}{b+c+d+a} + \dfrac{d+b}{a+c+d+b} = 2$

Comment: If $a,b\to0$ we have $S\to1$ and if $a,c\to0$ we have $S\to2$, so your boundaries are the best possible.

Comment: good to hear they are the best possible values.

Comment: I didn't know it was an IMO question but saw it once long time ago.

Comment: I saw it some time ago too on a training for the IMO, and went looking for it because there should have been a reference to its source. Turns out it is an IMO question.